# Low-profile, panel-mount connectors

Tags: connector, components, component-selection, interconnect

I'm working on a hobby project, a handwired ultra-low-profile computer keyboard with a 3D-printed case. The USB-C connector on my dev board is only 3mm tall, so it fits within the 4.5~5.0mm of available headroom. However, I need to add a second connector to link the two keyboard halves together, and this is the problem: I can't find a suitable connector that fits inside this volume.

Key requirements:

- 4+ contacts, all low power (5V, <500mA)
- Max 5mm height (width up to ~20mm is fine)
- Panel-mount (not PCB-mount)
- Supports some form of strain relief on the plug/free side

Circular connectors don't get this small—including the locking nuts, the smallest I've seen tend to be around 8~10mm dia. Even 2.5mm barrel jacks won't cut it. I also checked out Molex and JST, but the panel-mount options I could find were still around 8mm height minimum. Strain relief is also a concern for these header-style connectors. USB-C actually fits, but I would be using the connector out of spec, and it can't be panel-mounted (the main one only works because of my dev board's mid-mount setup).

Any suggestions? I really didn't expect this to be such a sticking point…

Comment: magnetic connectors

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for this recommendation! I found some enticing options on Aliexpress, but the parts come without housings (or dimensions). I would have to design my own, I guess. I found only one or two domestic options, all prohibitively expensive. It's looking like I'll have to tear up my 3D model and start again with a larger volume for the MCU—I don't like it, but I'm coming to terms with it.

Comment: you could also use SATA connectors

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Nano-D](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=exterior_conn&u=exterior_signal_conn&o=d_shell_conn&f=nano_d_conn&s=Nano-DA-15)*

ITT Cannon [pdf spec sheet](http://www.ittcannon.com/Core/medialibrary/ITTCannon/website/Literature/Catalogs-Brochures/ITT-Cannon-Nano-Microminiature-Connectors-Catalog.pdf).

- My site.

Comment: I had heard of micro-DSUB before, but never nano. These look fit for purpose, except they cost around $100 each! My fault for not adding a budget to the initial post, but this is out of my price range.